# Change font size on axis for excel chart with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to change the font size for the axis values to 11 from 9 on this chart:
[image: excel chart]

The chart is a whole worksheet & I have tried to run the macro tool and replicate what was in there to change to font size. From vba:

```
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Size = 11
    End With
```

I am unable to reproduce this in powershell. I have tried:

```
    $excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
    $ws = $excel.workbooks.open('file.xlsx').sheets('chart')
    $ws.axes().item(1).format.textframe2.textrange.font.size = 11
    $ws.axes().item(2).format.textframe2.textrange.font.size = 11
```

but the textframe2 object isn't initialized. I'm pretty stuck on how to proceed.

Thanks